# Span tag and content not rendering inside quill editor

Tags: quill

I have recently started exploring quill to implement a rich text editor. I want to render following html content in quill editor:
Second span

However when rendered, span tag is removed and its content is wrapped inside P tag and rendered. I learnt that as part of optimization quill removed span tags. But I really want span tag to render so I added a SPAN blot extending BlockEmbed. However after adding SPAN blot, nothing rendered in the editor. I don't understand what I am doing wrong; Here is the SPAN Blot:

```
let quill = require("quill");
let BlockEmbed = quill.import("blots/block/embed");

class SpanBlot extends BlockEmbed {
    public static create(value: any): any {
        let node = super.create(value);
        node.setAttribute("data-embed-id", value);
        return node;
    } 

    public static value(node: any): any {
        return node;
    }

    public static formats(node: any): any {
        let format: any = {};
        if (node.hasAttribute("data-embed-id")) {
            format.height = node.getAttribute("data-embed-id");
        }
        return format;
    }

    public formats(): any {
        let formats = super.formats();
        formats["span"] = SpanBlot.formats(this.domNode);
        return formats;
    }
 }

SpanBlot.blotName = "Span";
SpanBlot.tagName = "SPAN";
SpanBlot.class = "social";

export { BlockEmbed, SpanBlot };
```

Comment: Other thing I missed in question above is missing attributes. To retain attribute I added following logic, but this also doesn't seem to work:
     let spanDataEmbedIdAttribute = new Parchment.Attributor.Attribute("data-embed-id", "data-embed-id", {
            scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE
        });
        quill.register({'attributors/attribute/data-embed-id': spanDataEmbedIdAttribute})

Comment: So I found the problem, Span is by default Inline tag. Once I add a blot to render span tag extending BlockEmbed, span must be present in the whitelist collection. After updating the whitelist collection Span rendered. But to render children of span, I had to write following code inside create function:
public static create(value: any): any {
    let node = super.create(value);
    // Added below code to render the children.
    let childs = value.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
      node.appendChild(childs[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
    return node;
  }